# In bash loop script, how to refresh output in same line? (take the position of the last output)

Tags: bash, shell

For example,
I have output every second like

```
user@pc:
A
B
C
D
E
```

I want the output refresh from A to E in the same line(no new lines being created)

Thanks!

Comment: Use carriage return, `$'\r'`. Alternatively you can return to the beginning of the line with termcap, but I don't consider that advisable.

Comment: Why is `tput cr` "inadvisable"? (Other than that you probably want to follow it with `tput el`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `carriage return` character "`\r`". Check the difference between:

```
for x in $(seq 10); do printf "$x"; sleep 1; done
```

and

```
for x in $(seq 10); do printf "$x\r"; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: optionally `echo` with "e" and "n" parameters instead of `printf` will work as well:
`for x in $(seq 10); do echo -en "$x\r"; sleep 1; done`

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon where your input is coming from.

I would employ the below techniques.

**For files:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
echo -e "\e[1A" # moving the cursor back to the previously printed line
sleep 1s;
echo -ne "$line\e[K" # \e[K cleans the residues of the previous output.
done <file_name
echo
```

**For arrays:**

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0)

for i in ${arr[@]}
do
echo -e "\e[1A"
sleep 1s;
echo -ne "Waiting time : "$i" Seconds\e[K"
done
echo
```